# Che cosa vuol dire "per molti versi" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Le otto montagne*, di Paolo Cognetti, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Mi sarebbe piaciuto sapere che cosa faceva Bruno a quell’ora. Aveva acceso il suo fuocherello, o camminava da solo per la montagna, o andava avanti a lavorare fino al buio? **Per molti versi**, l’uomo che era diventato mi sorprendeva. Mi sarei aspettato di trovare, se non la controfigura di suo padre, almeno quella dei suoi cugini, o di uno dei muratori che una volta vedevo con lui al bar. Invece con quella gente non c’entrava nulla.

Non sono sicura di aver capito il significato dell'espressione "per molti versi" in questo brano. Ho cercato il termine "verso" in parecchi dizionari, ma ci sono molte accezioni e, a volte, questo mi confonde. Significa "a causa di molti aspetti diversi" (del modo di essere di Bruno), "da molti punti di vista" o qualcosa simile?

---

Un'espressione molto simile, che immagino abbia un significato analogo, l'ho trovata in questo brano del racconto *Cromo* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi (grassetto mio):

> La diagnosi era confermata e la patogenesi scoperta: si trattava adesso di definire la terapia. 
>       Questa fu trovata abbastanza presto, attingendo alla buona chimica inorganica, lontana isola cartesiana, paradiso perduto per noi pasticcioni organisti e macromolecolisti: occorreva neutralizzare in qualche modo, entro il corpo malato di quella vernice, l’eccesso di basicità dovuto all’ossido di piombo libero. Gli acidi si dimostrarono nocivi **per altri versi**: pensai al cloruro d’ammonio, capace di combinarsi stabilmente con l’ossido di piombo dando un cloruro insolubile ed inerte, e liberando ammoniaca.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il Sabatini Coletti, per [verso](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/V/verso_1.shtml) riporta la seguente accezione:

> 2 Modo, maniera: non c'è v. di farle cambiare idea || per un v., sotto
>   un certo aspetto, da un lato | in ogni v., sotto tutti gli aspetti, da
>   ogni punto di vista

L'espressione *in molti versi* quindi significa sotto molti aspetti, da molti punti di vista.

Comment: Grazie a questa e all'altra risposta ho potuto capire che "per altri versi" nel testo di Primo Levi significa "da altri punti di vista", "sotto altri aspetti". Sono state davvero utili per me.

Answer (score 2):

Significa "in molti sensi", "in molti aspetti", "da molti punti di vista". Il [dizionario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/verso3/) lo descrive così:

> d. locuz. avv. *A verso*, come si deve, al giusto modo: *fare le cose a v.*; e con uso attributivo: *un ragazzo a v.*, dabbene, ammodo. *Per un
>    v.*, da un lato, da un certo punto di vista, per un rispetto: *per un v. ha ragione, ma ...; per un v. sì, per un v. no; ora per un v. ora per un altro, chi ci rimette sono sempre io; chi per un v., chi per un altro, hanno tutti torto. Per ogni v.*, da ogni punto di vista, in ogni modo: *è una sistemazione conveniente per ogni verso*.